# Javascript variable displaying NaN

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables, numbers, integer

Can someone advise how I can get my final variable to display as a number (the value of my function variable) rather than NaN?

```
<form id="computeroi">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="col-1 pblue"> <p class="float-left"> 1. How many monthly visitors does your website get per month? </p>  <input type="number" value="0" id="monthlyvisitors" class="width-50" onchange="computeroi()"> </div>
                    <div class="col-1 pblue"> <p class="float-left"> 2. How many of those visitors are from a mobile device? </p>  <input type="number" value="0" id="mobilevisitors" class="width-50" onchange="computeroi()"> </div>
                    <div class="col-1 pblue"> <p class="float-left"> 3. What is your average deal worth ? </p>  <input type="number" value="0" id="dealworth" class="width-50" onchange="computeroi()"> </div>
                    <div class="col-1 pblue"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="width-25" id="submit" width="25"> </div>
                    <div class="col-1 "> <h1 id="newdealw"> </h1> </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

function computeroi() {
var monthlyv = document.getElementById('monthlyvisitors').value;
var mobilet = document.getElementById('mobilevisitors').value;
var dealw = document.getElementById('dealworth').value;

var newdeals = (mobilevisitors / monthlyvisitors); 
var newdealw = (newdeals * dealworth);

document.getElementById('newdealw').innerHTML = newdealw;
```

}

Comment: Your code declares the variables `monthlyv` and `mobilet`, and then it proceeds to use `mobilevisitors` and `monthlyvisitors` in the math. Those variables are not defined, so you get `NaN`.

Comment: the error is here
var newdeals = (mobilet / monthlyv); 
var newdealw = (newdeals * dealw);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mobilevisitors`,`monthlyvisitors`,`dealworth` isn't declared or defined anywhere in your method .

Rather your assign value of ids `monthlyvisitors`,`mobilevisitors`,`dealworth` into `monthlyv` ,`mobilet` ,`dealw`

```
var monthlyv = document.getElementById('monthlyvisitors').value;
var mobilet = document.getElementById('mobilevisitors').value;
var dealw = document.getElementById('dealworth').value;
```

Try like this

```
var monthlyv = document.getElementById('monthlyvisitors').value;
var mobilet = document.getElementById('mobilevisitors').value;
var dealw = document.getElementById('dealworth').value;

var newdeals = ( +mobilet / +monthlyv ); 
var newdealw = (newdeals * +dealw );
```

**N:b:** `+` sign before variable will consider it as a number.

Comment: Great responses guys solved it right away, silly oversight on my part! var newdeals = (3 / 100 (* monthlyv ));                                                                         I need the math to do the above actually but that won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
var monthlyv = document.getElementById('monthlyvisitors').value;
var mobilet = document.getElementById('mobilevisitors').value;
var dealw = document.getElementById('dealworth').value;

var newdeals = (mobilevisitors / monthlyvisitors); 
var newdealw = (newdeals * dealworth);
```

there are no `mobilevisitors` ,`monthlyvisitors` variables in your code.

also use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` accordingly before performing mathematical operations to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

there are no mobilevisitors ,monthlyvisitors variables in your code.
juste change the last two lines like this:

```
var newdeals = (mobilet / monthlyv); 
var newdealw = (newdeals * dealw);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared variable *mobilevisitors* or this one *monthlyvisitors* so you cannot get value. You should use the variable monthlyv and mobilet into which you are getting the value of these two thing (mobilevisitors and monthlyvisitors)